# Windows App Platform Platform - C# Execute code on page load

Tags: c#, uwp

How do I get code to execute as soon as a page is opened in my C# Universal Platform App project? Do I need to create a public event? If so what public event?

Answer (score 1):

Overload the [OnActivated()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.application.onactivated.aspx) method for handling your app coming back from suspend, and the [OnNavigatedTo()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227508) for navigation based calls in a Page.

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to get some code to run as soon as the first page in my app loads... any way of doing it since OnNavigatedTo only works if you're navigating to a page from another page? Cheers"

Comment: Like I said, Application.OnActivated() is called when your app is loaded, or coming back from suspend.  Have that call NavigationManager.NavigateTo() the page you need.  Then your OnNavigatedTo() will get called.